# How to show marker on map & show item on html tables using textbox? (google maps v3)

Tags: json, google-maps, asp.net-web-api

I am using this JSON(WebAPI) to view google markers on map - http://track.asiacom.co.th/fmswebapi/api/assetinfo.

I want to filter/search the markers by using html textbox. Upon searching, it will display the marker/s on map and it will also display the item/searched marker on html table at the same time. Pls. help how to achieved this?

Sample HTML

```
<div id="page-content"><div id="map-canvas"></div></div><table id="assetStatus" class="table table-condensed table-vcenter searchable" data-flat="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-header="false" data-search="false" data-show-refresh="false" data-show-toggle="false" data-show-columns="false" data-sort-name="id" data-page-list="[10, 20, 50, 100]" data-page-size="5" data-pagination="false" data-show-pagination-switch="false">/table>
```

Sample Javascript

```
function initialize() {

 var geocoder;
 var map;
 var markers = new Array();
 var marker;
 var assets = [];
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.7500, 100.4833);

var mapTypeIds = ["SEA"];
for (var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
    mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
}


var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,


    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,


    mapTypeControl: true,

    //mapTypeId: "",

    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        //style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,

        mapTypeIds: mapTypeIds,

        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },


    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },


    scaleControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true

}


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);

resize('map-canvas', 32);



// handle window resize
function resize(element, offset) {
    // get window height
    var height = 0;
    if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') height = window.innerHeight;
    else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    else if (document.body && document.bodyclientHeight)
        height = document.body.clientHeight;
    else if (screen.availheight)
        height = screen.availheight;
    else return;

    // update window size
    height = height - offset;
    if (height > 0)
        document.getElementById(element).style.height = height + "px";
}

//Transit Layer - off
//Start
/*=================================================*/
//var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
//transitLayer.setMap(map);
/*=================================================*/
//End


//Traffic Layer - On
//Start
/*=================================================*/
var controlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
$(controlDiv).addClass('gmap-control-container')
             .addClass('gmnoprint');

var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
$(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control');
$(controlUI).text('Traffic');
$(controlDiv).append(controlUI);

var legend = '<ul>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #30ac3e">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #30ac3e"> &gt; Smooth Traffic</span></li>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #ffcf00">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #ffcf00"> Slow Moving Traffic</span></li>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #ff0000">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #ff0000"> &lt; Heavy Traffic</span></li>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #c0c0c0">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #c0c0c0"> No data available</span></li>'
           + '</ul>';

var controlLegend = document.createElement('DIV');
$(controlLegend).addClass('gmap-control-legend');
$(controlLegend).html(legend);
$(controlLegend).hide();
$(controlDiv).append(controlLegend);

// Set hover toggle event
$(controlUI)
    .mouseenter(function () {
        $(controlLegend).show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(controlLegend).hide();
    });

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function () {
    if (typeof trafficLayer.getMap() == 'undefined' || trafficLayer.getMap() === null) {
        $(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control-active');
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        trafficLayer.setMap(null);
        $(controlUI).removeClass('gmap-control-active');
    }
});

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(controlDiv);

//Traffic Layer - On
//End
/*=================================================*/



//SEA Layer - On
/*=================================================*/
//Start

map.mapTypes.set("SEA", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
        return "http://a.tile.osm-tools.org/osm_then/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    name: "Multilanguage",
    alt: "Show Standard",
    maxZoom: 20

}));

//End
/*=================================================*/

setMarkers(map, assets);


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = 
       event.latLng.lat() + ', ' + event.latLng.lng();
});

}

function setMarkers(map, assets) {


// Add markers to the map


// Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
// The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
// traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
// coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
// coordinate.
var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
};



var url = 'http://track.asiacom.co.th/fmswebapi/api/assetinfo';

$.getJSON(url, function (assets) {


    for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {

        var asset = assets[i];
        var category = asset.Category;
        var engine = asset.LastPos.Engine;
        var company = asset.Company;
        var vechs = asset.Name;

        if (assets.indexOf(i) !== -1) continue;

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(asset.LastPos.PosY), parseFloat(asset.LastPos.PosX));



        //Background marker

        var icon = "";
        switch (asset.LastPos.Engine) {
            case "MOVE":
                icon = "move";
                break;
            case "IDLE":
                icon = "idle";
                break;
            case "STOP":
                icon = "stop";
                break;         
        }


        icon = "http://track.asiacom.co.th/track/Dashboard/img/" + icon + ".png";




        // Category image
            var markerCategory = "";
            switch (asset.Category) {
                case "Car":
                    markerCategory = "car";
                    break;
                case "Truck":
                    markerCategory = "truck";
                    break;
                case "Van":
                    markerCategory = "van";
                    break;
                case "Bus":
                    markerCategory = "bus";
                    break;
                case "Motorcycle":
                    markerCategory = "motorcycle";
                    break;
                case "Recovery Veh":
                    markerCategory = "truck";
                    break;
                case "Lorry":
                    markerCategory = "truck";
                    break;
                case "10 Footer Lorry":
                    markerCategory = "truck";
                    break;
                case "14 Footer Lorry":
                    markerCategory = "truck";
                    break;
            }


        var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
        pictureLabel.src = "http://track.asiacom.co.th/track/Dashboard/img/categories/marker/" + markerCategory + ".png";


        //marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //Default Google Maps
            marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            //========================================

            raiseOnDrag: true,
            labelContent: pictureLabel,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 11),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelStyle: { opacity: 1 },
            category: category,
            engine: engine,
            company: company,
            vechs: vechs,
            //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            //icon: image,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon, new google.maps.Size(28, 28), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(14, 14)),
            shape: shape,
            title: asset.LastPos.Asset,
            zIndex: asset.LastPos.PosZ

        });

            markers.push(marker);   



            /**
             * Function to filter markers by category
             */
            $(function () {

                $('.SelectCategoryFilter').on('change', function () {
                    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

                    for (i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
                                marker = markers[i];
                                // If is same category or category not picked
                                if (marker.category == selected || selected.length === 0) {
                                    marker.setVisible(true);

                                }
                                     //Categories don't match 
                                else {
                                    marker.setVisible(false);

                                }
                            }             

                });

            });


            /**
           * Function to filter markers by engine
           */
            $(function () {

                $('.SelectEngineFilter').on('change', function () {
                    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                    for (i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
                        marker = markers[i];
                        // If is same engine or engine  not picked
                        if (marker.engine == selected || selected.length === 0) {
                            marker.setVisible(true);

                        }
                            //Engine Status don't match 
                        else {
                            marker.setVisible(false);

                        }
                    }

                });

            });


            /**
            * Function to filter markers by company
            */
            $(function () {

                $('.SelectCompanyFilter').on('change', function () {
                    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

                    for (i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
                        marker = markers[i];
                        // If is same engine or engine  not picked
                        if (marker.company == selected || selected.length === 0) {
                            marker.setVisible(true);

                        }
                            //Engine Status don't match 
                        else {
                            marker.setVisible(false);

                        }
                    }

                });

            });


            /**
            * Function to filter markers by Vehicles
            */
            $(function () {

                $('.SelectVechsFilter').on('change', function () {
                    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();


                    for (i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
                        marker = markers[i];
                        // If is same engine or engine  not picked
                        if (marker.vechs == selected || selected.length === 0) {
                            marker.setVisible(true);

                        }
                            //Engine Status don't match 
                        else {
                            marker.setVisible(false);

                        }
                    }

                });

            });



        //InfoBox Content
        var assetTag = asset.Tag;
        var assetAddress = asset.LastPos.Location;
        var assetSpeed = asset.LastPos.Speed;
        var assetMileage = asset.LastPos.Mileage;
        var assetFix = asset.LastPos.Fix;
        var assetTimestamp = asset.LastPos.Timestamp;
        var assetLat = asset.LastPos.PosY;
        var assetLong = asset.LastPos.PosX;
        var assetBattery = asset.LastPos.Battery;



        //Date InfoBox

        //Convert Timezone
        var Bangkok = moment.tz(assetTimestamp, "Asia/Bangkok");

        //Format UTC
        var timestamp = moment(Bangkok.format()).format("D-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm:ss A");

        //  Format for Asset Status Infobox Color
        // =================================================================
        var assetColor;

        if (asset.LastPos.Engine == 'MOVE')
            assetColor = "success";
        if (asset.LastPos.Engine == 'IDLE')
            assetColor = "warning";
        if (asset.LastPos.Engine == 'STOP')
            assetColor = "danger";


        // InfoBox
        var assetContent = "<div id='infobox'><h4 id='firstHeading' class='firstHeading'>" + vechs + "</h4>" + "<p class='text-default text-justify bg-" + assetColor + " pad-all' style='height:auto'>"
                        + assetAddress + "</p>" + "<table visibly='vehicle:status' class='table table-bordered table-vcenter'>" + "<tbody>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<span class='text-bold'>Device:&nbsp;" + assetTag + "</span>" + "<br />" + "<span class='text-bold'>Category:&nbsp;" + category + "</span>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<td>" + "<span class='text-bold'>Status:&nbsp;" + engine + "</span>" + "<br />" + "<span class='text-bold'>Speed:&nbsp" + assetSpeed + "</span>" + " </td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<span class='text-bold'>Mileage:&nbsp;</span>" + assetMileage + "<br />" + "<span class='text-bold'>" + "Battery:&nbsp;" + assetBattery + "</span>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<span class='text-bold'>" + assetFix + "</span>" + "<br />" + " <span class='text-normal'>" + timestamp + "</span>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "</tbody>" + "</table>" + "</div>";




        //Marker Details - Info Window
        /*=================================================*/
        //Start

        var infoboxOptions = {
            //content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
            content: assetContent,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 150,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 14),
            zIndex: null,
            boxStyle: {
                background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                opacity: 1,
                width: "280px"
            },
            closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            isHidden: false,
            enableEventPropagation: false
        };



        //Define the infobox
        assets[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);

        //Open box when page is loaded
        assets[i].infobox.close(map, marker);

        //Total Vehicles
        var $result = $('#total-vehicles');
        var rows = document.getElementById('assetStatus').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
        $result.text(rows)



        //Table Vehicle List
        $("#assetStatus").find("tbody tr").each(function (index) {

            $(this).on(
                'click',
                function () {

                    map.panTo(markers[index].getPosition());

                  }

            );

        });


        // Click Marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {

            return function () {

                assets[i].infobox.open(map, this);
                map.panTo(this.position);
                //setTimeout(function () { initialize(); }, '30000'); //Refresh
                setTimeout(function () { AutoRefresh(); }, '3000'); //Refresh
                setTimeout(function () { assets[i].infobox.close(map, marker); }, '60000'); //Auto close infobox
            }

        })(marker, i));

    }


    return assets;
}

        //End
        /*=================================================*/


 )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the marker part, once you send a request and receive back desired info, parse it, extract location info and you can use the following documentation to put marker on the map: [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple). There are many options such as set marker display to invisible and visible again, etc. The documentation in the given example contains useful functions which can help you achieve desired effect.

Comment: I need sample code on how to display marker using textbox‏